# How to deserialize Avro content from BigQuery using Apache Beam?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently trying to read a data table from Google BigQuery using Apache Beam/Google Dataflow. I have extracted the avro schema from BigQuery and generated the Java classes from that avro schema. As I don't want to read all the table, I use an SQL query to get the last record. And since the documentation states that [`BigQueryIO.readTableRows(....)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#readTableRows--) is slower than [`BigQueryIO.read(SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, T>)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#read-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-), I tried to use [`BigQueryIO.readWithDatumReader(...)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#readWithDatumReader-org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.avro.io.AvroSource.DatumReaderFactory-) the following way

```
        return pipeline.apply("Read from BigQuery query", 
                BigQueryIO
                    .readWithDatumReader((AvroSource.DatumReaderFactory<SupplyChain>)
                            (writer, reader) -> new SpecificDatumReader<>(SupplyChain.getClassSchema()))
                            .fromQuery(query)
                            .withQueryLocation("EU")
                            .usingStandardSql()
                            .withMethod(BigQueryIO.TypedRead.Method.DIRECT_READ)
                       );
```

Unfortunatly, it fails with the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "instance" is null
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptors.extractFromTypeParameters(TypeDescriptors.java:354)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptors.outputOf(TypeDescriptors.java:411)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptors.outputOf(TypeDescriptors.java:420)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.inferCoder(BigQueryIO.java:1070)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1247)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$TypedRead.expand(BigQueryIO.java:914)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:559)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:508)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:194)
    at com.auchan.hermes.prd03.Run.source(Run.java:59)
    at com.auchan.hermes.prd03.ReadDataFromBigQueryTest.test_can_read_data_from_BigQuery(ReadDataFromBigQueryTest.java:71)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline$1.evaluate(TestPipeline.java:323)
```

After having read the source code, I've noticed there is in the `BigQueryIO.read(SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, T>)` source code a call to `.setParseFn(parseFn)` which is missing from the `BigQueryIO.readWithDatumReader(...)` method. Is there something else to do? Am I missing something?